# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined | Angular 4

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I'm getting this error when I try to print a data from the JSON I get from the API. It does print correctly however this error appears on the console and I'm not sure how to fix it.

**HTML**

```
{{datas[0].dimension}}
```

**TS**

```
datas: Data[];
this.abcService.getDatas().subscribe(datas => {
  this.datas = datas;
  console.log(datas);
});
```

**JSON got from the API (console.log)**

```
(1) [{…}]
0:
  dimension:"bla bla bla"
__proto__:Object
length:1
```

**Full error on console**

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (GraphicsComponent.html:11)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.es5.js:13113)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12260)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12620)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12552)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12261)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12620)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.es5.js:12578)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12256)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12620)

DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 17, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
component: (...)
componentRenderElement:(...)
context:(...)
elDef:{index: 16, parent: null, renderParent: null, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, …}
elOrCompView:(...)
elView:{def: {…}, parent: {…}, viewContainerParent: null, parentNodeDef: {…}, context: GraphicsComponent, …}
injector:(...)
nodeDef:{index: 17, parent: {…}, renderParent: {…}, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, …}
nodeIndex:17
providerTokens:(...)
references:(...)
renderNode:(...)
view:{def: {…}, parent: {…}, viewContainerParent: null, parentNodeDef: {…}, context: GraphicsComponent, …}
__proto__:Object
```

Obs: HTML does print "bla bla bla"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It should be

```
{{datas && datas[0]?.dimension}}
```

For more details see this thread

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6798

Another solution is initialize property with empty array:

```
datas: Data[] = [];
```

and then just write

```
{{datas[0]?.dimension}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add safe navigation operator to check data is present before accessing since you are getting the response from an asynchronous call

```
{{datas[0]?.dimension}}
```

Comment: it can't be . did you restart and check

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because your binding data in your view is blank while angular compile html because Observable.subscribe gives you data in the future when serve response received.

So you can initialize it to avoid error or undefined test first and then use it.

```
{{datas[0]?.dimension}}  //will work file
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The two answers that were posted 1.5 hours before yours cover what needs to be covered. There's no point in repeating things ad nauseam.

Comment: the point is `You are getting this error because your binding data in your view is blank while angular compile html because Observable.subscribe gives you data in the future when serve response received.` during compile time it is not available which is not mentioned in any of the answer which inspire me to add my answer

Comment: [Sajeetharan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46350131/1906307): "you are getting the response from an asynchronous call" says essentially the same thing.

Comment: I think I am highlighting that point as that is important. This answer deserve to be here as it highlight the most important point of the problem and will help lot of people to get out of that situation quickly!